# Flutter Speech_recognition - IOS

Tags: flutter, dart, speech-recognition

I have tried implementing flutter speech_recognition (https://github.com/rxlabz/speech_recognition) package in my project. It is working fine in Android, but in IOS the onRecognitionComplete() is not called as soon as the sentence is done.

After talking something, it takes some time around like 10 to 20 seconds to call the onRecognitionComplete().

Is there any way to overcome this issue or any other alternate package to proceed with?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: please show some code

Comment: @MaadhavSharma  ,I used the same code which they used for the example application in the github [https://github.com/rxlabz/speech_recognition/blob/master/lib/speech_recognition.dart] repo.